# How to test OAuth JWT authentication in SF CRM

Tags: api, oauth2, jwt, postman

I'm trying to implement and test [JWT Bearer authentication](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5), I've created a key pair on my local machine and created a connected app in my sandbox and uploaded my `.crt` file.

Is there a way I can test my authentication is working with a tool like Postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that you can do this from within the same org that you're trying to auth with (I'm only about 98% confident that it does work), but you can use an anonymous apex window to test this.

You can use Apex to construct everything you need, but the simpler approach is to use some of the classes in the `Auth` namespace ([Auth.JWT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWT), [Auth.JWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWS.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWS), and [Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange)) to make it pretty dead simple.

This is assuming that you have the certificate uploaded to Salesforce via "Certificate and Key Management" (type that into the search bar in the setup pages to find it).

The basic example would be

```java
Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
// test.salesforce.com is used for sandboxes
jwt.setAud('https://test.salesforce.com');
jwt.setIss('<client id of your connected app here>');
jwt.setSub('my.user@company.tld.TheSandbox');
// This is how long the signed JWT has (in seconds) to make it to Salesforce before
//   Salesforce will reject it, not how long your resulting token is valid for
jwt.setValidityLength(60);

Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'cert_api_name_in_salesforce');

Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange tokenExchange = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token', jws);

Http httpObj = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res;

// Yes, the extra space after "Bearer" is intentional (and required)
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tokenExchange.getAccessToken());
req.setEndpoint('https://<your cs pod>.salesforce.com/services/apexRest/<your Url Mapping here>');
req.setMethod('POST'); // or GET, or PATCH, or whatever verb you're expecting

res = httpObj.send(req);
```

Comment: I've got another sandbox that I can connect from, but I get this error `Line: 19, Column: 58. Variable does not exist: getAccessToken`

Comment: @DeploymentFailure ah, that's meant to be a method.